# VBA Error 1004: Copy paste Range with Formats

Tags: excel, vba, range, paste

I have a rows of data, that skip at various points.
The data is organized by days, grouped in weeks.
The data itself is a Colour Coded Value.
The need is delete one week of data.

I am attempting to copy a Range of cells(Single Row) and copy the values 7 cells to the left

```
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(MoveRow, MoveColumn + 7), Cells(MoveRow, LastWeek)).Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(MoveRow, MoveColumn)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(MoveRow, MoveColumn)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

I am able to copy by creating anouther loop, and copy the cells one at a time, but as there are hundreds of columns, and thousands of rows, I would prefer the code to be completed before next week, when I have to run it again...

During Execute, I get Run-time Error '1004'.

I also tried :

```
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(MoveRow, MoveColumn + 7), Cells(MoveRow, LastWeek)).Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(MoveRow, MoveColumn), Cells(MoveRow, LastWeek - 7)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(MoveRow, MoveColumn), Cells(MoveRow, LastWeek - 7)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Other answers to similar questions, have yet to produce results.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(MoveRow, MoveColumn)).` should just be: `ActiveSheet.Cells(MoveRow, MoveColumn).`  Range wants a string address or two cells.  If you just want one, `Cells()` is sufficient.